# Remove Side boxes from magento homepage

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community, home

How can I remove these side boxes: "Call Us Toll Free", "Free Shipping", "Now accepting PayPal" ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can remove this blocks by their name like by writing the following code in your themes local.xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

for other blocks please find their name from xml file and use like above.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find these CMS blocks under the CMS tab on the back end.

You can simply click through them and disable the ones that reflect what you do not want on the home page.

Alternatively, you can view the element, find the name of the block, then view the layout.XML of your theme, and manually disable the ones you do not want by commenting them out.

Answer (score 1):

For the PayPal box I went to

> admin->system->payment_methods->paypal_express_checkout->configure->advanced_settings->frontend_experience->paypal_product_logo->no_logo.

This setting will remove the PayPal logo from the right hand side bar.